# Limit function parameter type only to keys of interface with specific type

Tags: typescript

Lets assume I have an interface called `dto`. It has several fields in it with different types.

I want to have a function that can only accept paramater whos name is one of keys of `dto` and whos type is only number.

```js
interface dto {
    aaa: string,
    bbb: number,
    ccc: boolean,
    ddd: number,
}

const variable = <dto> {
    aaa: "hello",
    bbb: 42,
    ccc: false,
    ddd: 914    
};

function test(param: <SOME MAGIC HERE>): number {
    return variable[param] + 10;
}

console.log(test("aaa")); // error, because dto.aaa has type of string
console.log(test("ccc")); // error, because dto.ccc has type of boolean
console.log(test("eee")); // error, because "eee" id not among keys of dto
console.log(test("bbb")); // ok, will return 52, because dto.bbb has type of number and "bbb" is among keys of dto
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

```js
type OnlyNumbers<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends number ? Prop : never
}[keyof T]

function test(param: OnlyNumbers<dto>): number {
  return variable[param] + 10;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot generic

Comment: A more general solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72493871/238884)