# Omitting keys of a particular type

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

Here is what I would like:

```
const a = getNumber({a: 3, b: "three"}, "a"); // a is type of number (or even 3)
const b = getNumber({a: 3, b: "three"}, "b"); // does not compile
```

The closest I have gotten is

```
type NumberOnly<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends number ? number : never;
}
const getNumber = <T extends Record<string, any>, 
                   K extends  keyof NumberOnly<T>>(t: T, k: K):NumberOnly<T>[K] 
     => t[k];
```

`a` is type `number` and `b` is ... `never`.

Close but no cigar.

---

The suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079395/238884) only works if the base type is *fixed*, which weirdly would have worked for my original problem, but if the type is generic, Typescript does not understand that `t[k]` is a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit function parameter type only to keys of interface with specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079207/limit-function-parameter-type-only-to-keys-of-interface-with-specific-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the problem:

```
type NumberOnly<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends number ? K : never]: T[K]
}
```

We use the `as` operator inside the index signature. When `T[K]` is not `number` the key will be omitted.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgVwLYCMoCcDyA7ANmAHgBUA%20GAXhgG9gY6YBtAaRgEtsYBrKMAewDMYRGAEMAzkOYBdGFAAeIKNgAmE7MjToYAfhgsAXDGxQAbhimGi04AF9gwAMa9sYkDADmUEIlQYKMAlohWQUlVRgAJSgndGUCV3R2dwAaUWwwEmSglnlFFQluPkEfTRx8YhJgEgAKEEtUzkMmAEpDEowywlJpCjIQBk4pAG57R2dXUX9Pbw0MaqoRQwBmVJRDACIQAAt0KCh1m1T1kXXmoZgxlzcUKa929HnFmBWYNZhNnb2Do5RT86A)